# Time out/not compiling with Annotated Equations using tikz in latex

Tags: graphics, equations, compiling, annotations

I've been trying the Annotated Equations in Latex: https://github.com/synercys/annotated_latex_equations

However, I have only used three and it is causing timeout errors and cannot compile in my .pdf or in separate graphics to include.

For example, this is one I tried which first caused the problem. Any suggestions?

I've included an example I've tried in this template provided for Annotated Equations: https://www.overleaf.com/5578564312nrfqvbngfmst

insurance.tex

````
\begin{equation}
    maxNetValue = (\tikzmarknode{p}{\highlight{red}{p}} - \tikzmarknode{g}{\highlight{blue}{g}})Loans + (\tikzmarknode{g}{\highlight{blue}{g}} - \tikzmarknode{d}{\highlight{plum}{d}})Deposits
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>=stealth,nodes={align=left,inner ysep=1pt},<-]
        % For "p"
        \path (p.north) ++ (0,2em) node[anchor=south west,color=red!67] (scalep){\textbf{predicted value of y (the dependent variable)}};
        \draw [color=red!57](p.north) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=red]scalep.south east);
        % For "g"
        \path (g.south) ++ (0,-1.5em) node[anchor=north west,color=blue!67] (mean){\textbf{new input variable}};
        \draw [color=blue!57](x.south) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=blue]mean.south east);
        % For d
        \path (d.north) ++ (0, 1.8em) node[anchor=north west,color=Plum!85] (scalep){\textbf{interest rate on Deposits}}
        \draw [color=Plum!85](d.north) | - ([xshift=0.3ex,colour=Plum!]scalep.north west);
\end{tikzpicture} ```
````

Comment: please show a complete test document not just a fragment. Also what is giving a timeout, tex itself has no time limits, are you using overleaf?

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, sorry I'm fairly new to latex. Yes I'm working in overleaf. I've updated my question with a link to the example I've tried using.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Remove from the preamble `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`

(2) There were many errors in the files `insurance.tex` and `banking.tex`.

[image: a]

Use these files instead so that the build completes without errors.

There will still be some work left to arrange the figures in the two-column environment and to add spaces between them and the text.

New file `banking.tex`

```
%File banking.tex

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.7\columnwidth}
    \vspace{3\baselineskip}
    
\begin{equation}
    %maxNetValue = (p-g)Loans + (g-d)Deposits
    maxNetValue = (\tikzmarknode{p}{\highlight{red}{p}} - \tikzmarknode{g}{\highlight{blue}{g}})Loans + (\tikzmarknode{g}{\highlight{blue}{g}} - \tikzmarknode{d}{\highlight{green}{d}})Deposits
\end{equation}
%$g =$ \textit{opportunity cost}\\
%$p =$ \textit{interest rate on Loans}\\
%$d =$ \textit{interest rate on Deposits}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>=stealth,nodes={align=left,inner ysep=1pt},<-]
        % For "p"
        \path (p.north) ++ (0,4em) node[anchor=south west,color=red!67] (scalep){\textbf{predicted value of y (the dependent variable)}};
        \draw [color=red!57](p.north) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=red]scalep.south east);
        % For "g"
        \path (g.south) ++ (0,-1.5em) node[anchor=north west,color=blue!67] (mean){\textbf{new input variable}};
        \draw [color=blue!57](g.south) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=blue]mean.south east);
        % For d
         \path (d.north) ++ (0, 1.8em) node[anchor=south west,color=green!80] (scalep) {\textbf{interest rate on Deposits}};
        \draw [color=green!85](d.north)   |- ([xshift= 0.3ex,color=green!80]scalep.south east);        
\end{tikzpicture}

 \vspace{4\baselineskip}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

New file `insurance.tex`

```
%%File insurance.tex

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.7\columnwidth}
    \vspace{3\baselineskip}

\begin{equation}
    \tikzmarknode{q}{\highlight{red}{q}}- \tikzmarknode{p}{\highlight{blue}{p}} - \tikzmarknode{pc}{\highlight{green}{pc}} = {[q-(1+c)p]}- \tikzmarknode{X}{\highlight{cyan}{X}}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>=stealth,nodes={align=left,inner ysep=1pt},<-]
        % For “qX”
        \path (q.north) ++ (0,4em) node[anchor=south west,color=red!67] (scalep){\textbf{consumer price paid for insurance}};
        \draw [color=red!57](q.north) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=red]scalep.south east);
        % For "g"
        \path (p.south) ++ (0,-3.5em) node[anchor=north west,color=blue!67] (mean){\textbf{probability of claim for X value}};
        \draw [color=blue!57](p.south) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=blue]mean.south east);
        % For pcX
        \path (pc.north) ++ (0, 1.8em) node[anchor=south west,color=green!80] (scalep) {\textbf{expected administrative costs of claim}};
        \draw [color=green!85](pc.north)   |- ([xshift= 0.3ex,color=green!80]scalep.south east);
        %For X
        \path (X.south) ++ (0,-1.5em) node[anchor=north west,color=cyan!67] (mean){\textbf{claim for X value to be paid by insurer}};
        \draw [color=blue!57](X.south) |- ([xshift=-0.3ex,color=cyan]mean.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

 \vspace{4\baselineskip}
\end{wrapfigure}
```